# if else conditions not working in ejs after I hosted using aws and nginx

Tags: ejs

if else conditions working fine in the localhost but not working after I hosted.

```
const productDetails = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    userSession = req.session;
    const id = req.query.id;
    const products = await Product.find();
    const productData = await Product.findById({ _id: id });
    if (productData) {
      res.render("singleProduct", {
        isLoggedin,
        id: userSession.userId,
        product: productData,
        products: products,
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect("/home");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};




<% if(id) { %>
    <%- include('../partials/userLoggedinHeader') %>
    <% }else { %>
    <%- include('../partials/userHeader') %>
    <% } %>


<% if(id){ %> 

<a class="primary-btn" onclick="addToCart('<%=product._id%>')">Add to Cart</a>
<a class="icon_btn" onclick="addToWishlist('<%=product._id%>')"><i class="lnr lnr lnr-heart"></i></a>

<% }else {%> 

<a class="primary-btn"  href="/addToCart?id=<%=product._id%>">Add to Cart</a>
<a class="icon_btn" href="/AddToWishlist?id=<%=product._id%>"><i class="lnr lnr lnr-heart"></i></a>

<% } %>
```

here I have rendered id and it is working fine in localhost but the second 'if' not working after I hosted using aws and nginx. Can someone tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see what version of node is installed on the aws instance? That could be causing some of your problems if it isn't the same as the one you are using on your computer

Comment: I have checked, aws having  v18.12.1 and my computer's is v18.12.0 .